# Python logger not writing logs on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logfile

I have a web application deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk. To put it simply, I have two different python files that writes logs to the same log file ("implementation.log")

**scriptA.py**

```
    logger = logging.getLogger('LGB_Implementation')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger_handler = logging.FileHandler('implementation.log')
    logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s- %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
    logger.info('Completed configuring logger() for back-end')

    def A():
        logger.info('Entered method A()', exc_info=1)
        logger.info('Exiting method A()', exc_info=1)

    def B():
        logger.info('Entered method B()', exc_info=1)
        logger.info('Exiting method B()', exc_info=1)
```

**scriptB.py**

```
logger = logging.getLogger('LGB_Implementation')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger_handler = logging.FileHandler('implementation.log')
logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s- %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
logger.info('Completed configuring logger() for back-end')

def C():
    logger.info('Entered method C()', exc_info=1)
    logger.info('Exiting method C()', exc_info=1)

def D():
    logger.info('Entered method D()', exc_info=1)
    logger.info('Exiting method D()', exc_info=1)
```

When testing locally, the logger performs exactly as it should -- Logs are written to "implementation.log" as it accesses methods A, B, C and D. However, when running on AWS EBS, the "implementation.log" file only has logs of method A even when we go into method B, C and D. Anyone know why or how to fix this?

EDIT: Method A is the first method the web app accessed when starting.